# How can I fix this node to react connection to make my Login page work?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm trying to make a login authentication.
I'm using an express server that gives a token to the user when he submits his username and password.
My problem is, that when I'm submiting that data, I get the following error:

> POST http://localhost:3000/api 404 (Not Found) Uncaught (in promise)
> SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

This has to be an issue with both parts of my app interacting. But I have tried changing "app.get" for "app.use" or changing the "/api" to other kind of name. Couldn't solve it. I will write the routes for every file in case you think I have a routing error.

This is my node code (app/server/server.js)

```
const express = require('express');
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
const app = express();
const cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors());

app.get("/api", (req, res) => {
  res.send({
    token: 'test123'
  })
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
   console.log(`Server is running on ${PORT}`)
});
```

This is the part of my React app that interacts with node (app/client/src/Login.js)

```
const loginUser = async (credentials) => {
 return fetch('/api', {
   method: 'POST',
   headers: {
     'Content-Type': 'application/json'
   },
   body: JSON.stringify(credentials)
 })
   .then(data => data.json())
}
const Login = ({ setToken }) => {
const [username, setUserName] = useState();
  const [password, setPassword] = useState();

 const handleSubmit = async e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const token = await loginUser({
      username,
      password
    });
    setToken(token);
  }
return (
<div>Here is the login container</div>
)
```

A custom hook I'm using

```
import { useState } from 'react';

const useToken = () => {
  const getToken = () => {
    const tokenString = localStorage.getItem('token');
    const userToken = JSON.parse(tokenString);
    return userToken?.token
  };

  const [token, setToken] = useState(getToken());

  const saveToken = userToken => {
    localStorage.setItem('token', JSON.stringify(userToken));
    setToken(userToken.token);
  };

  return {
    setToken: saveToken,
    token
  }
}

export default useToken;
```

Finally, my App.js (app/client/src/App.js)

```
const App = () => {
const { token, setToken } = useToken();
if(!token) {
return <Login setToken={setToken} />
}

 return (
<>
here is my app
</>
)
```

Comment: Two issues, one you're sending a POST request and have only registered a GET route. Secondly, unless your client & server are on the same host & port, that `/api` fetch isn't going to the API, its going to the client. Please provide some detailsa obut what specifically isn't working. Maybe some error messages if applicable

Comment: There. I expanded my question with the error I receive in console and a custom hook I'm using to manipulate the token I should receive. I don't know how to solve what you say, but I will get into it.

Comment: That error is indicative of the second problem I mentioned. Make sure to send your request to something like `localhost:8080/api`. This kind of debugging is probably off-topic for SO though so I'm going to stop the comment chain discussion here.  https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/create-a-simple-react.js-component-with-backed-node.js-api This link may be useful. Best of luck

Comment: I'm sorry but i don't know what you mean

Comment: The previous comment solved my problem! thanks btw

Comment: Whish port is your express and react application running respectfully